# Facebook FQL : how to get album's location ID?

Tags: facebook-fql

When getting information about album, I can get only location name :

```
select aid, owner, location from album;
```

But I need also a place ID for further manipulations.

I can't just query "place" table to return me places that have the name of album location ("name" column is not unique and not indexed in place table).

How can I get that place ID?

Comment: Found it. It can be taken from a "photo" table, when getting a photo associated with that album.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It can be taken from a "photo" table, when getting a photo associated with that album:

```
select aid, place_id from photo where pid = (select cover_pid from album where aid = you_post_attachment_fb_object_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The user can put *anything* they like into this field – so the info you’re getting from there does not necessarily have to correspond to any specific place on Facebook.

For example, I could name my album “Photos from my Holidays in 2012”, and type “New York, London, Berlin, Tokyo” into the field – so you can not expect the API to return a specific location id in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is don't work in 100% cases. Because album can be empty or locations of album/cover photo can be different.